# Debian Wheezy, old computer, DMA read error, scales modes down until PIO

Tags: hard-drive, debian, dma

I got an old computer that I wanted to install debian wheezy on.

Well that works but,at every bootup I get those errors:

ata1.00: failed command: READ DMA

when it happens the kernel softresets the device and tries again in a lower and lower DMA modes, when its through the lowest mode it tries PIO and then successfully accesses the drive again.

It happens right after the bootloader.

What can I do to make DMA possible or if not somehow force the kernel to not even try DMA and go to PIO mode directly?

As for compatibility, the bios supports DMA modes up to "5"

It happens with every IDE disk I still have and thats about 7 different.
One of them is 20 years old and still runs flawless in other computers.

Answer (score 0):

you can always boot kernel with ide=nodma to prevent this issue.